# DynamicRelationshipType in Spring Data Neo4j or defining relationship types at runtime

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Can I specify relationship type at runtime??

I am creating a set of relationshipEntity objects within an Entity using something like

```
@Fetch
@RelatedToVia(type="RELATED_IN_SOME_WAY", direction = Direction.BOTH)
Set<ThingRelationship> relationships = new HashSet<ThingRelationship>();
```

where ThingRelationship is

```
@RelationshipEntity
public class ThingRelationship {

public ThingRelationship() {
    super();
}

//incremental neo4j set ID
@GraphId Long nodeId;

//Start and end nodes
@StartNode Thing startThing;
@EndNode Thing endThing;

//Relationship Type
@org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.RelationshipType
String relationship;
```

However I DONT want to specify the relationship type (**type="RELATED_IN_SOME_WAY"**) at compile time but rather at runtime.  When I remove type="RELATED_IN_SOME_WAY I get an error that a default type must be defined

In Neo4j such a runtime relationship type I think requires the use of **DynamicRelationshipType** however I dont think the Spring Data Neo4j supports this concept.

Am I correct and if so is there anyway around this problem?  Do I need to dump Spring Data Neo4j and go to use the Core API instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In Neo4j such a runtime relationship type I think requires the use of DynamicRelationshipType however I dont think the Spring Data Neo4j supports this concept.

From the [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#reference%3aprogramming_model%3arelationships%3arelationshiptypeprecedence)

> Note
>
> Because dynamic type information is, well, dynamic, it is generally
>   not possible to read the mapping backwards using SDN. The relationship
>   still exists, but SDN cannot help you access it because it does not
>   know what type you gave it. Also, for this reason, we require you to
>   specify a default relationship type, so that we can at least attempt
>   the reverse mapping.

So while the dynamic relationship is still created, it can't use that information to retrieve the nodes/relationships back from the Neo4j db. The default relationship is required so that SDN can at least return the known relationship.

- Am I correct and if so is there anyway around this problem? Do I need to dump Spring Data Neo4j and go to use the Core API instead?

You can use the SDN to create all dynamic relationships you want using the `@RelationshipType` but you can't retrieve it back using the default API. You can use write your own Cypher or write traversal code and attach it to your repository or a node property using `@Query`.